# How to sort value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to sort in JavaScript for my case? I will input some value like given below:

**Input:**

```
banana
apple
orange
lichi
air
airness
```

I have found so:

```
$('.alphabetized').click(function(event) {
    var textareaInput=$('.textareaInput').val();
    var strToArr=textareaInput.split(',');
    var arrUniqueVal=arrUnique(strToArr);
     $('.textareaInput').val(arrUniqueVal.sort().join(','));
    console.log(arrUniqueVal);
    //alert("ok");
});
```

My code is work if i input something like this:

```
banana,apple,orange,lichi,air,airness
```

How can i split inputted array so that i can get result of my required inputted value (See input value in question) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split based on new line instead of `,`

```
var strToArr=textareaInput.split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

```js
$('.alphabetized').click(function(event) {
  var textareaInput = $('.textareaInput').val();
  var strToArr = textareaInput.split(/[\r\n]+/);
  var arrUniqueVal = strToArr; //arrUnique(strToArr);
  $('.textareaInput').val(arrUniqueVal.sort().join('\n'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows=10 class="textareaInput"></textarea>
<button class="alphabetized">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Oh i forgot.Helped.

Answer (score 2):

if items are separated in different line, then try

```
textareaInput.split('\n');
```

Your code will look like

```
$('.alphabetized').click(function(event) {
    var textareaInput=$('.textareaInput').val();
    var strToArr=textareaInput.split('\n');
    var arrUniqueVal=arrUnique(strToArr);
     $('.textareaInput').val(arrUniqueVal.sort().join(','));
    console.log(arrUniqueVal);
});
```

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud glad to help.